# Convert jQuery function code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the jQuery function I have

```js
$(".top1").onmousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    $(document)
      .bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e) {
        rotateOnMouse(e, $('.top'));
      });
  }
});
```

I tried to covert it in to plain JavaScript function. I tried the following method.

```
document.querySelector(".top1").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

      e.preventDefault(); // prevents the dragging of the image.
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        console.log('dfs')
        // document
        //     .bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function (e) {
        //         rotateOnMouse(e, $('.top'));
        //     })
      }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Where's the html you are using? What is the expected behaviour? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: am getting error in the below commented part... document.bind() part

Comment: Also do not add an event handler  in an event handler

Comment: So, why are you converting that code to plain JS?

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this code**, i have updated it

if you have used **class** then you must iterate over it else use **id** for single events

```
var top1 = document.querySelector("top1");
var rotateImg = document.querySelector("rotateImg");

for (i = 0; i < top1.length; i++) {
    top1[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            for (j = 0; j < rotateImg.length; j++) {
                rotateImg[j].addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                    rotateOnMouse(e, top1[i]);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection. You can't call `addEventLsitener` on that.

Comment: `var top1 = document.querySelector(".top1");`

Comment: thanks @mplungjan for correcting me. :)

Comment: But you did not pay enough attention. You need the dots

Comment: `querySelector` only returns the _first_ found element. Calling `addEventLsitener` on that isn't the same as `$("selector").on<event>`. `getElementsByClassName` would've worked, but you have to iterate over all results.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is likely ok here. OP has top1 - he likely could have used an ID - but without HTML we'll never know

Comment: That's an assumption I disagree with. It also teaches the OP that `querySelector` is the same as the jQuery selector, which simply isn't true.

Comment: thanks all of you,,that worked..........now how can i unbind mousemove event on mouseup using pure javascript?